# how to display the item listbox and index in one time

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

I want to make the list box have the selected index first and then get the item in one time, how to do that?

```
Dim Itemname
    Itemname = lstShipper.SelectedIndex
```

I just want the item refer to the index.

because the item maybe can be update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking, but I am going to guess you want to update another control when the index of the ListBox changes.

[ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

From that event you can get the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem.

`Dim curItem As String = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Hope that helps.